# Unwanted Sitecore URL

Tags: urls

I am able to access a page using the path:

`https://<<My Domain>>/Sitecore/content/page_path`

This has been crawled by Google, I don't want these URL's to be accessible.

I would like to know what is the correct way to handle these? Should this be resolved and URL be changed? or should we be blocking the requests for anything containing Sitecore/Content in request URL?

**My Site definition is:**

database="web" domain="extranet" disableClientData="false" 
cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="250MB" cacheRenderingParameters="true" 
renderingParametersCacheSize="100MB" allowDebug="true" enablePreview="true" 
enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" enableAnalytics="true" 
notFoundItem="/sitecore/content/ZZZ/ZZZX/Home/Error"/>

Thanks,

Samridhi

Comment: I think that your site is not configured correctly. Can you add definition of your site into your question? Follow this doc  https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/view-configuration-changes.html#UUID-08abcbb4-1e84-44db-28fc-14efc95ee1b4_id__Display_the_Sitecore and put into your question everything which is between <sites> and </sites> xml elements which should look like this https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Configuring%20Sites%20in%20web,-d-,config%20File.aspx

Comment: My Site definition is : <site patch:before="*[@name='website']"
                     name="XYZ" physicalFolder="/ABC"
                     virtualFolder="ABC"
                     rootPath="/sitecore/content/ZZZ/ZZZX"
                     contentStartItem="/sitecore/content/ZZZ/ZZZX/Home"
                     startItem="/Home"
                     language="en" contentLanguage="en"

Comment: database="web" domain="extranet" disableClientData="false"
                     cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="250MB"
                     cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="100MB"
                     allowDebug="true"
                     enablePreview="true" 
                     enableWebEdit="true" 
                     enableDebugger="true"
                     enableAnalytics="true"
                     notFoundItem="/sitecore/content/ZZZ/ZZZX/Home/Error"/>

Comment: @samridhisachdeva can you add the entire `<sites>` block from your `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` to the question (not in a comment)? That will help others who are trying to help you.

Comment: Hi @samridhisachdeva have you found solution of this? i have the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to block them. Ideally, Google should never have been told about these URLs in the first place, it looks like you might have some mismanaged Site Url Generation going on elsewhere.

But for purposes of getting these links OFF Google again, you need to block them. Easiest way to do it, is to use a Rewrite rule.  Something like:

```
<rule name="sitecore predixes" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^sitecore/?(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.hostname.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

(you need to create a proper match url, to filter out `/sitecore/content`)

Then enable this rewrite rule on IIS and tell Google to reindex.

Secondly; you need to ensure that all the URLs you generate for your site are correct. Here is a good resource to help you get started: [Safely Defining Multiple Sites in Sitecore](https://www.berndtgroup.net/thinking/blog/sitecore/safely-defining-multiple-sites-in-sitecore)

Answer (score 0):

Following the best SEO practises would be the best.

1. Implement canonical URL on all pages
2. Consider using Robots.txt
3. Make sure your XML Sitemap is correct
4. Maybe using a 301 Redirect to strip out the /sitecore/Content/ part of the URL

Comment: You are trying to find solution for the current situation not the root cause of the problem. Redirection will not help here. This must be a problem of misconfiguration of site in Sitecore

Comment: ya I don't want to go with redirects option, also I don't have the Robots.txt in my website.

Comment: There is no misconfiguration though. Since Sitecore 5, it has been possible to use http://hostname/sitecore/content/home to reach the home node. It's by design.

Comment: so what's the way to restrict these URLs on public site ?

Comment: If you must, override the item resolver in the pipeline. I will not recommend this approach however as I'm sure by doing so, something else will be broken. Hence my original answer.